# String concatenation gone functional

Tags: scala

Suppose there are 3 strings:

```
protein, starch, drink
```

Concatenating those, we could say what is for dinner:

Example:

```
val protein = "fish"
val starch = "chips"
val drink = "wine"

val dinner = protein + ", " + starch + ", " + drink
```

But what if something was missing, for example the protein, because my wife couldn't catch anything. Then, we will have: `,chips, drink` for dinner.

There is a slick way to concatenate the strings to optionally add the commas - *I just don't know what it is ;-)*. Does anyone have a nice idea?

I'm looking for something like:

```
val dinner = protein +[add a comma if protein is not lenth of zero] + starch .....
```

It's just a fun exercise I'm doing, so now sweat if it can't be done in some cool way. The reason that I'm trying to do the conditional concatenation in a single assignment, is because I'm using this type of thing a lot in XML and a nice solution will make things..... nicer.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When you say "it may be absent", this entity's type should be `Option[T]`. Then,

```
def dinner(components: List[Option[String]]) = components.flatten mkString ", "
```

You would invoke it like this:

```
scala> dinner(None :: Some("chips") :: Some("wine") :: Nil)
res0: String = chips, wine
```

In case you absolutely want checking a string's emptiness,

```
def dinner(strings: List[String]) = strings filter {_.nonEmpty} mkString ", "

scala> dinner("" :: "chips" :: "wine" :: Nil)
res1: String = chips, wine
```

Comment: Scala has `nonEmpty`, Java 1.6 has `isEmpty`... why compare length when all you want is to know whether the string is empty or not?

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the answer.

Comment: `filterNot(""==)` is a bit more concise than `filter(_.nonEmpty)`

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Sure it is more concise, but you are describing how to test the condition, instead of informing what the condition is.

Comment: @Daniel OP's requirement is that the string "is not lenth of zero" (sic). Calling the parameterless `nonEmpty` method is just as much "how to test" this as is calling the `==` method with a `""` argument. Sure, its name gives us a clue to what the method does (but so does `==`), and it makes the code read more like English, but is there anything more to it than this? Are we just saying that parameterless methods are inherently better? & only if the method name surpasses a threshold level of similarity with the requirement? (side-note: should have used `filter(""!=)` for full golfing points!)

Comment: @LuigiPlinge To be succinct, I disagree. :-)

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral isEmpty is native to String; nonEmpty is an expensive augment.

Comment: @som-snytt why did you edit my answer? I disagree. This discussion in the comments clearly shows different opinions, but may confuse people after you've edited the answer.

Comment: @som-snytt With value classes, `nonEmpty` is little more expensive than `isEmpty`.

Comment: @AlexanderAzarov I think it was the curly brace that got me started. I'll edit it back.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral the StrOps isn't optimised away, even with AnyVal.

Answer (score 14):

You're looking for mkString on collections, maybe.

```
val protein = "fish"
val starch = "chips"
val drink = "wine"

val complete = List (protein, starch, drink) 
val partly =  List (protein, starch) 

complete.mkString (", ")
partly.mkString (", ")
```

results in:

```
res47: String = fish, chips, wine
res48: String = fish, chips
```

You may even specify a start and end:

```
scala> partly.mkString ("<<", ", ", ">>")
res49: String = <<fish, chips>>
```

Answer (score 13):

```
scala> def concat(ss: String*) = ss filter (_.nonEmpty) mkString ", "
concat: (ss: String*)String

scala> concat("fish", "chips", "wine")
res0: String = fish, chips, wine

scala> concat("", "chips", "wine")
res1: String = chips, wine

scala>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never seen the * being used in Scala. Shows how long I've been around Scala :-p. Does it have a name? Reminds me of pointers in C++.

Comment: It's called "repeated parameter" in "stairway book" ("Programming in Scala" by M.Odersky, L.Spoon & B.Venners). I think "variable length argument" is fine too.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderAzarov, that will teach me for using a book as reference before reading cover to cover. Yip, it's there alright: Page 156 in the printed version of the second edition, to be exact ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This takes care of the case of empty strings and also shows how you could put other logic for filtering and formatting. This will work fine for a `List[String]` and generalizes to `List[Any]`.

```
val input = List("fish", "", "chips", 137, 32, 32.0, None, "wine")

val output = input.flatMap{ _ match { 
  case None => None
  case x:String if !x.nonEmpty => None
  case x:String => Some(x)
  case _ => None
}}
.mkString(",")

res1: String = fish,chips,wine
```

The idea is that `flatMap` takes a `List[Any]` and uses matching to assign `None` for any elements that you do not want to keep in the output.  The Nones get flattened away and the Somes stay.

If you needed to be able to handle different types (Int, Double, etc) then you could add more cases.

Answer (score -4):

```
println(s"$protein,$starch,$drink")
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work, it will print the wrong stuff if `protein` is an empty string.

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)